# SQL, using data from a number of separate tables to receive an output

Tags: sql, oracle

So my tables I'm working with look like the following:

> Book(BookID, Title)
>
> Author(BookID, AuthID)
>
> Writer(AuthID, PubID, FirstName, LastName)
>
> Publisher(PubID, PubName, Country)

And I'd love to change them to make more sense, but I'm not allowed to even change their names at this point.

Anyway, I have two separate pieces of code that I want to run together. So it's the result of this:

```
select Book.Title
from Book
join Author
on Book.BookID=Author.BookID
group by Book.Title, Book.BookID
having count(*) >= 2
```

with this:

```
select AuthorID
from Author
join Publisher
on Author.PubID=Publisher.Publisher
where Publisher.Country like 'Australia'
```

Initially I thought `INTERSECT` might work but I quickly realised that because they're not matching fields, I need something else. And the fact that `Writer` and `Publisher` have to be linked via `Author` is throwing me off completely.

Is there a way to do this save going back to the table and changing it to something less unnecessarily complex?

I've been going through the list of statements and whatnot on trying to find a solution, but I'm not sure which one I'm supposed to be looking at. Perhaps something with `GROUP` in it? So anything, just a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to find all books with more than one author published in Australia?

If so, the query would look something like this:

```
select b.Title
from Book b join
     Author a
     on b.BookID = a.BookID join
     Writer w
     on w.AuthId = a.AuthId join
     Publisher p
     on w.PubId = p.PubId
where p.Country like 'Australia'
group by b.Title, b.BookID
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: Yes. That's it! So you can join multiple tables? Is there a practical limit to doing this?

Comment: The number of joins may become a performance consideration under certain conditions. Among others, factors such as data volume, data distribution and indexing would play a part in the determination of what is practical. However, these are intermediate/advanced database topics, which you will come to later on if you're in your early stages of learning about databases.

Comment: Alright. I'll focus on doing what I can do right first. In regards to using this method, what happens when you want to retrieve all columns from, say like in the one above, the Book table? A `SELECT *` won't work because it's not a `GROUP BY` expression, right? So is the only option listing everything I want?

Comment: @Shianra . . . It is safe and even ANSI standard syntax to choose `b.*` in the select list.  You are aggregating by the primary key of the table, so you can take any field from the table.  And, I wouldn't worry about the number of joins.  MySQL can handle many more than four tables.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a small conceptual misunderstanding blocking your way here.

The two queries can be combined into a single query, and return the results you want, via multiple joins involving all these tables.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem - separating it into problems instead of one. Would such a thing as thing be possible with `SELECT *` to retrieve all information about a Publisher, or would I have to list every column required in order to use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: In almost all cases using `SELECT *` is a bad idea; you should specify the columns in this case, if for no other reason: readability.